# PHP send mail to Excel list

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have a long Excel list which holds user names, mail addresses and a PIN number. I want to generate an auto mail like "Dear `$name`, your PIN is `$pin`" and send to `$mail` where `$name`, `$mail`, and `$pin` variables will come from an excel file..(there are three columns)

Can any one please share any idea or sample code?

**EDIT For bounty**
Here's a screen print of my csv file.  I want to read data as two dimensional array from csv file and populate an email.

[image: my csv file]

Comment: Are there specific problems you're having? Is this for a one-off, or something you'll need to run regularly, or "on demand"?

Comment: I didn't try any code. I will use it just once, there is a long linst on a friend, it will take days to send those mails one by one, so i wanted to populate an auto mail.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Here is the best option** :

```
1. convert Excel to CSV
2. Import CSV to database
3. Fetch the contents of database to your php page.
4. Loop your contents and send mail.
```

Advantage :

1. You dont want any external library or plugins
2. Simple coding, (fetching data from DB and mailing)

**Another option is read csv and send mail** :

Here is the code to read data from CSV and send mail : This is just an example code, you edit it as per your requirement and csv field names.

```
$row              = 1;
if (($handle      = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num      = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";   
        $row++;

        $to          = $data[2]; // as per your CSV shown in question.
        $subject     = 'Your subject';
        $message     = 'Your mail content';
        $headers     =  'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
                        'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
                        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant way. And if you do not want to write code lines, you can use phplist (http://www.phplist.com/). There is an option to import csv files as mailing lists. You can use custom attributes for users, and edit messages, etc... 
But sometimes longer to configure it, than write a short code :)

Comment: I'm not a php coder, but i do want be one:)
For the moment the shortest way would be best, so i tried a few different libraries with no success.. Almost all of them have depricated methods or ect..

Comment: And, if you ever need to export it as an excel file from the database there are good libraries for doing that. This for example: https://code.google.com/p/php-excel/

Comment: @qwerty : Using phpmyadmin you can directly export to excel, you dont need any libraries for that.

Comment: @themarchoftheblackqueen : Added the code to read CSV and send email...I have not tested the code let me know if any issue.

Comment: @PrasanthBendra Thanks for your guideness but when i tried 'echo $to;' instead fo 'mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);' it prints my_name,my_pin, my_mail. but i want just to get 'my_mail' in offset 2

Comment: @themarchoftheblackqueen : Yes, there was a issue, my bad, corrected the code please check it now. :)

Answer (score 3):

First, if you don't mind using a large PHP library, I would definitely vote for PHPExcel (http://phpexcel.codeplex.com). You can parse the excel file row-by-row to get the user info.

Second, if you have a large database, you should consider SendGrid (http://sendgrid.com) for sending the mails. They have the header configuration optimal for all the receiving mail clients.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

With this package you can read an XLS file: http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/ (Simple to use and there lot of examples). 
It parses an XLS file to an associative array.
After this you can run through the array, getting from that the data you need, and pass parameters to a mail function. (But I recommend not to use the normal mail function but use phpMailer instead, http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)

And as the other commenter said, you can convert your XLS file to a csv. In this case use the fgetcsv function of PHP http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php.

Comment: thanks for answer, but the methods on your link are deprecated

Comment: Which methods are deprecated? fgetcsv() certainly isn't, and PHP Excel Reader still works as far as I'm aware

Comment: The phpmailer moved to http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/ . My link was not so perfect :D. 
fgetcsv is still working on php 5.3 and will not be deprecated in 5.4 as i red. The development of the excel reader as i know finished or paused in 2010, but working fine for me in (PHP5.3 too). They are working fine for many years. This might be the reason that they seems to be old :)

Comment: @MarkBaker not fgetcsv(), i can't remember now(i need to try again, if you want i can).. I'm not a PHP coder as i had said on a different comment above, i'm still trying

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a PHP solution, but since this is one-off need, there's no point in rolling your own solution. You might like to give something simpler a try.

I recently linked up my mail server to my gmail account (as an alias), and took advantage of one of the many available [Mail Merge](https://www.google.ca/search?q=gmail%20mail%20merge) programs people have made. It's as simple as:

1. Creating an email with placeholder values such as $%Name% and $%PIN%, and saving it as a draft.
2. Opening a mail merge spreadsheet in your google drive, pasting in your source data, and clicking run.

You can also try any number of free packaged  mail merge solutions, like the [xsMerge](http://www.thexs.ca/xsmerge) chrome app.

Comment: my problem is with looping through the data not with mail

Comment: @themarchoftheblackqueen Oh I see, so you are looking for a way to either import the spreadsheet or unzip/decode and parse the xml straight from php?